# 'Conclusio sequitur ex premissis' or 'sequitur conclusio ex premissis'?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, word-order, philosophy-terms, logic

I'd like to know how best to translate "the conclusion follows from the premises".
'Conclusio sequitur ex premissis', 'sequitur conclusio ex premissis', or something else entirely?

Comment: Both are perfectly correct, but might be used in different types of contexts. Latin word order is relatively free, so questions about word order are generally not answerable without a specific context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I give some real examples taken from medieval latin:

> *ex his praemissis haec sequitur conclusio* (Saint Lawrence of Brindisi)
>
> *sequitur ex praemissis ista conclusio* (Ockham)
>
> *haec / ista conclusio sequitur ex praemissis* (Ockham)
>
> *ex praedictis praemissis sequitur ista conclusio* (Ockham)
>
> *conclusio sequitur ex talibus praemissis* (Ockham)
>
> *sequitur conclusio ex praemissis* (Bacon, Ockham)

Please note that the correct word is ***praemissis*** and not *premissis*

Comment: I was confused about 'praemissis' versus 'premissis' because I've seen both used. For example, in "Summule Logicales" by Petrus Hispanus, 'premisses' is used frequently, yet I don't recall ever seeing "praemissis'. That being said, I've seen praemissis used a lot in other texts and, apart from in "Summule Logicales", haven't seen premissis used. What do you make of that?

https://books.google.com/books?id=Qi8QAQAAIAAJ&vq=figura&dq=subalterne+universalis+affirmativa+particularis+affirmativa&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: The ancient latin form is praemissis: the passage from the diphtong -ae- to -e- is a typical trait of the medieval latin by means of his pronunciation in the late imperial period, which gradually gains ground. In the manuscripts, the ligature æ was simplified in ę and then became the simple e.

Comment: Does the historical context matter? For example, if the relevant context is the Roman Republic then one would use ancient Latin and if the relevant context is medieval Scholasticism then one would use medieval Latin?

Also, if I am to understand the above translations correctly, would it be correct to say "sequitur conclusio ex propositio" if I wanted to use 'propositio' in place of 'praemissa'?

Comment: You could do it, but you have to write "ex propositione", in ablative. It is better to use always the classical forms writing in Latin today